When does Postgres store data in TOAST storage and what are the implications of this?
According to the documentation for CREATE TABLE:

PLAIN must be used for fixed-length values such as integer and is inline, uncompressed. MAIN is for inline, compressible data. EXTERNAL is for external, uncompressed data, and EXTENDED is for external, compressed data. Writing DEFAULT sets the storage mode to the default mode for the column's data type. EXTENDED is the default for most data types that support non-PLAIN storage. Use of EXTERNAL will make substring operations on very large text and bytea values run faster, at the penalty of increased storage space.

And the docs for CREATE TYPE:

plain specifies that data of the type will always be stored in-line and not compressed. extended specifies that the system will first try to compress a long data value, and will move the value out of the main table row if it's still too long. external allows the value to be moved out of the main table, but the system will not try to compress it. main allows compression, but discourages moving the value out of the main table...All storage values other than plain imply that the functions of the data type can handle values that have been toasted

And of course the TOAST docs say the page size is 8k.

If I have a table with a TOAST-able field with default storage configuration, and insert a row that is <8k, where will the TOAST-able field be stored and why? Does the data type of the field matter (I'm thinking text vs jsonb vs bytea, for example)?
If I have a table with a TOAST-able field defined with STORAGE MAIN and insert a row <8k, will the TOAST-able field data be compressed? Does this always happen? What if I'm using bytea?
What are the performance implications of storing part of a row in TOAST storage? The docs above say substring operations are faster if the data are stored in TOAST storage- why would it matter where the data are stored physically? It seems like this would incur an extra disk seek per row (except in a seq scan); is that correct?
What are the performance implications of NOT storing variable length data in TOAST storage? It seems like the DB would have to read the row up to the first four bytes (or less?) of the variable length field, stop, interpret the length of the field, and then resume reading the rest of the row (or something like that). While not ideal, this still saves a seek. Is that correct?

Assume a default GUC, and none of these tables are TEMPORARY.

"The docs above say substring operations are faster if the data are stored in TOAST storage"  No, they say it will be faster if they are stored uncompressed.

Indeed, the docs say: "Use of EXTERNAL will make substring operations on wide text and bytea columns faster (at the penalty of increased storage space) because these operations are optimized to fetch only the required parts of the out-of-line value when it is not compressed."
